# Calculate top & lowest ten percent values in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, function, subset, rbind

Load library and sample data:

```
library(MASS)
View(Cars93)
Cars93$ID=1:93
```

Now I want to subset `Cars93` so that new df (`sub0l` and `sub0h`) have all IDs with all columns but with only top (for df `sub0h`) and lowest 10% values (for df `sub0l`) in column 17:25, and rest values (11-100 quartile for df `sub0l` and 0-90 quartile for df `sub0h`) could be changed to NA.

Here is my attempt to create two dfs with top ten% or lowest ten% values from columns 17:25:

```
sub0l <- do.call(rbind,by (Cars93,Cars93$ID,FUN= function(x) 
  subset(Cars93, (Cars93[,17:25] <= quantile(Cars93[,17:25], probs=  .10)))))

sub0h <- do.call(rbind,by (Cars93,Cars93$ID,FUN= function(x) 
  subset(Cars93, (Cars93[,17:25] >= quantile(Cars93[,17:25], probs=  .91)))))
```

I get an error while subseting top and lowest ten quartiles of columns:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(Cars93, ,17:25) : undefined columns selected
Called from: `[.data.frame`(Cars93, ,17:25)
```

Any better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following returns what you are looking for

```
sub0l <- cbind(Cars93[,1:16], sapply(Cars93[,17:25], 
                  function(i) ifelse(i > quantile(i, probs=0.1, na.rm=T) | is.na(i), NA, i)))

sub0h <- cbind(Cars93[,1:16], sapply(Cars93[,17:25], 
                 function(i) ifelse(i < quantile(i, probs=0.91, na.rm=T) | is.na(i), NA, i)))
```

The `sapply` function loops through each variable in the data.frame, to which the quantile function is applied. Within each pass, the generic function accesses the variable as a vector through the "i" argument. This is then passed to the `ifelse` function. This function takes a look at each element of the vector, i and assesses whether it passes the test. If the element passes the test, it is assigned NA, if it fails, its original value is returned. This process will work great for variables that are numeric.

If some of the variables are not numeric, then you can add an additional check in the `sapply` functions as below:

```
sub0l <- cbind(Cars93[,1:16], 
               sapply(Cars93[,17:25], 
                 function(i) {
                   if(is.numeric(i)) {
                     ifelse(i > quantile(i, probs=0.1, na.rm=T) | is.na(i), NA, i)))
                   }
                   else i
                 }))

sub0h <- cbind(Cars93[,1:16], 
               sapply(Cars93[,17:25],
                 function(i) {
                   if(is.numeric(i)) {
                     ifelse(i < quantile(i, probs=0.91, na.rm=T) | is.na(i), NA, i)
                   }
                   else i
                 }))
```

before beginning the operation described above, the generic function checks if the vector i is of type numeric (in R, this is either mode double or integer, see `?typeof` for a discussion of the core element types in R). If this test fails, the vector is returned by `else i`. If the first test passes, then the process described above begins.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I still get an error "Error in quantile.default(i, probs = 0.1, na.rm = T) :   factors are not allowed. Called from: quantile.default(i, probs = 0.1, na.rm = T)"

Comment: different but similar data set

Comment: Thanks; yes, there were factors in the data. Could please you explain your code a bit so it may help others who read this post? It is ok if you don't want to. For other readers who might face similar problem; try these codes before running above code with answer: `sapply(df, mode)` , `sapply(df, class)` ,  `which( colnames(df)=="column name" )` for checking mode, class and location of column in df.